# Why does updating my code signing certificate break Adobe AIR application updating?

Tags: air, adobe, certificate

I have an AIR application that I have been signing with my Verisign certificate. I have just renewed this certificate for another two years. But when I make and sign a new version of my AIR application, the update fails (with a misconfigured error message).
This warning is in the AIR documentation:

> When you sign an AIR application with a certificate, whether it's a developer self-signed test certificate, or the official certificate of your company, that version of your AIR application can only ever be updated with another version of your application published with the same certificate.

Does anyone know a way to tell the updater framework, or whatever, that this is simply a renewal of the same certificate? Verisign were told to simply renew the certificate so I am sure nothing other than expiry dates changed.

Or am I doomed to having a broken updater every two years?

Thanks
Adrian

Answer (score 2):

Just found what looks like the answer:

To publish an update for an existing AIR application while using a new or renewed signing certificate, use the ADT -migrate  command to apply a certificate migration signature. A migration signature is a second signature applied to an AIR file using the original certificate. The migration signature validates that an application update was produced by the owners of the original certificate

Comment: Also note that you can only use the migration tool for 180 days after the expiry date of the original certificate.

Comment: Here is a blog post that (partly) explains how you can cope with cases where you have a long standing application signed by many certificates.
http://blogs.adobe.com/simplicity/2010/01/update_strategies_for_changing.html